# Resetting the user password doesn’t work for Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

as requested by the Azure support team we are raising this issue.
The issue we face is that resetting the user password doesn’t work for Azure B2C.
We followed the steps as outlined here: http://aka.ms/d_LzkR2Yfz
We do get a temporary password for the user, but when trying to login the system responds with an “Invalid username or password.“.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be a azure support request.

Comment: For B2C local account, we should let user reset their password by themselves. However, you could also rest the user password via Azure AD Graph API

Answer (score 3):

There is [a known issue](https://github.com/twright-msft/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-limitations.md#issues-with-admin-initiated-password-reset-on-the-azure-portal) that is related to administrators resetting passwords for local account users via the Azure Portal.

It is recommended that administrators reset passwords for local account users using [the Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#ResetUserPassword).

Comment: They need to fix this, it's been too long.

Answer (score 0):

and why that indusians don't fix that portal issue so long time...